# Where can I find an API for the English Premier League?

Tags: api, live

I'm trying to build a "fantasy team" site but I can't seem to find an API for the English Premier Leauge. Is there one for free or do I have to pay to get that information?

Thanks!

/Niklas

**Edit**
My idea was to charge $10 for entering a team and to have a payout structure like a tournament, with percentages of the main pot. Like 20% to the winner, 15% to the runner up etc...
Would that count as commercial use?

Do you know if Yahoo's API (YQL) can do this?

Comment: Are you talking about scores? Games, goals, etc?

Comment: You will have have to consider, that in most cases, somebody already owns the rights to use the names of the clubs and players. If you plan to create a public site, you will probably need a license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to use one from [Score24](http://www.score24.com/), which was awesome.

It's not free though, I believe we paid about 50€ / league / month, but that was 2005.

But it's fast, really fast. There just a couple of seconds between a goal and the XML message they send. Really cool.

They also have the teams with all the players before each game and they give you goals, cards and everything you need.

Have a look!

Comment: I just added a second requirement =) Do you think I could use this for my site?

Comment: Score24 has no moral limitations what so ever. They deliver data to many of the largest betting sites. But make sure you have a good business plan before you start hooking up yo (and depending on) services that comes with a cost.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/.  It's got lots of data about football teams, players and matches, and it's free for non-commercial use.

Comment: These guys are extremely unresponsive. The API access is upon application only and I have not received an acceptance or rejection notice since I applied 6 months ago.